# Extract numbers from an string, save them into an array, and put them back into a string

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I've been using stackoverflow to learn a lot about both PHP and JS (incl jquery) so I tend to google all the time but I didn't find an exact reply to this question

I have many strings with words mixed with numbers, like:

"60 reviews from 12 people, 20% of users"

This is an example but it can be much more complex ("word_one 45 word_two word_three 657 word_four 32% word_five USD20")

The use is content localisation:

I want to retrieve the numbers and save them into an array **-> done**

I want to match these numbers with what I already have in the database, i.e. if I have

en: "2 reviews from 2 people, 2% of users"

es: "2 comentarios de 2 personas, el 2% de los usuarios" **-> done too**

Now what I want to do is to replace the numbers in the matching string extracted from the database (all of them are "2" because I saved them this way, to avoid the plural-singular problem) with the numbers from the original string in English.
Example:

**I have this in English:**

"60 reviews from 12 people, 20% of users"

**I have this in the database:**

en: "2 reviews from 2 people, 2% of users"

es: "2 comentarios de 2 personas, el 2% de los usuarios"

**I want this in Spanish:**

"60 comentarios de 12 personas, el 20% de los usuarios"

Code:

```
$pattern = '!\d+!';
$repv = preg_replace($pattern, "2", $v);

preg_match_all($pattern, $v, $matches);     
$matchesnb = count($matches, 1);
$pattarray = array_fill("0", "1", array_fill("0", ($matchesnb-1), $pattern));
$reptarget = preg_replace($pattarray, $matches, $dbdata[1]);
```

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: You described what you're working on, you showed a snippet of your code (with variables defined elsewhere). Now, would you mind asking a question?

Comment: Hi, the question is "I want this in Spanish" ;) it wasn't very clear.. I just added the one missing $pattern variable.

Comment: You're doing a simple text-to-text mapping translation, which means the numbers in both texts are meaningless, they just have to be replaced in a fixed order. Any chance you can use, like `%reviews% reviews from %people% people, %perc% of users` as template, so you can have "meaningful" numbers, and much easier when you want to edit your sentence?

Comment: Unfortunately no because the text is much more complex than this only example:
This is an example but it can be much more complex ("word_one 45 word_two word_three 657 word_four 32% word_five USD20")

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save your template sentences in your database ready to be used with the [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function?

```
$str = array(
    'en' => '%d reviews from %d people, %01.1f%% of users',
    'es' => '%d comentarios de %d personas, el %01.1f%% de los usuarios'
);
$res = sprintf($str['es'],60,12,20);
```

---

**EDIT:** The ordering of words in a sentence is not the same in all the languages. For that reason I think numbering the arguments is a better approach. I added the Turkish option to the array below to show how arg1 and arg2 switch as well as how the percent sign changes place (it's put before, instead of after the number in Turkish, for example).

```
$str = array(
    'en' => '%1$d reviews from %2$d people, %3$01.1f%% of users',
    'es' => '%1$d comentarios de %2$d personas, el %3$01.1f%% de los usuarios',
    'tr' => '%2$d kullanıcıdan %1$d yorum, tüm kullanıcıların %%%3$01.1f\'si'
);
$res = sprintf($str['es'],60,12,20);
```

Comment: As the values seem to be in a numerical array, I suggest `$re = vsprintf($str['es'], $dbdata)` as a slight improvement.

Comment: @Mytskine Makes sense. I'm so used to using sprintf that I totally forgot the vsprintf function. Thanks for the improvement.

Comment: Unfortunately no because the text is much more complex than this only example: This is an example but it can be much more complex ("word_one 45 word_two word_three 657 word_four 32% word_five USD20")

Comment: @Julien it does not matter at all, you can have 100s of values that need to be replaced in a single string. All you need to do is properly escape necessary places in your string(s).

Comment: The thing is that I don't know what the strings look like and cannot tell... this was given only as an example

Comment: In anyway, just beware, the sentence structure is not the same in all the languages. So the first number in an English sentence might actually point to the second number in, say a Spanish sentence.